# Remove element from html string in JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

So, I am pretty stumped as to how to exclude a sub children from getting selected in JQuery...

Here is my HTML structure in my string:

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td>some data I don't want.</td>
       <td>
       <table><tr><td>more data I don't want</td></tr></table>
       Text I want to extract here.
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Note: I didn't choose this. I am trying to parse the text "Text I want to extract here" out of this structure that comes from some arbitrary xml feed.

Here is my test JQuery: (d is the HTML string)

```
$('tr > td:eq(1) > table', d).remove();
var c = $('tr > td:eq(1)', d).text();
```

The first line does not remove the table. I test the selector and it does manage to select the element. Am I using the wrong method to remove the element?

I had also tried using `not()` and `replaceWith()` with no luck.

```
$('tr > td:eq(1)', d).not('tr > td:eq(1) > table').text();
```

and

```
$('tr > td:eq(1) > table', d).replaceWith("");
```

I am open to other selection methods that will retrieve only the text within that specific td.

Comment: you say `exclude a sub children`, which sub children are you trying to exclude? or do you mean exlude all of them.

Comment: It's entirely possible this isn't viable at all, but [would it be easier to use a regular expression instead?](http://jsfiddle.net/bemnn/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You state that *"`d` is the HTML string"*.

This means that when you do this:

```
$('tr > td:eq(1) > table', d).remove();
var c = $('tr > td:eq(1)', d).text();
```

...you're creating elements from the same ***unmodified*** string twice.

---

You need to create elements out of it ***once***, then cache those elements.

```
var $d = $(d);  // create the elements out of the string, and cache the set

$d.find('tr > td:eq(1) > table').remove();  // remove table from the cached set
var c = $d.find('tr > td:eq(1)').text(); // target the <td> and get its text
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ckcDx/)**

---

Or, because of jQuery's `.end()` method, you could do it all in one shot like this:

```
var c = $(d).find('tr > td:eq(1)')
            .children('table')
            .remove()
            .end()
            .text();
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ckcDx/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

What is `d`?  When I created an example of your js/HTML it seemed to run fine.  You can see it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/v7Qm2/

Is it possible that you are limiting the scope to `d` when you should not be?

**NOTE:**

Just to clarify, my answer is that your code looks fine and appears to do what you want.  I think the issue is that you are limiting the scope of your selector when you should not.

Comment: This seems more like questions than answers.

Comment: @RightSaidFred, updated in an attempt to clarify what my answer is.

Comment: That looks better, but unfortunately your answer isn't correct. @Bri is not doing DOM selection. The `d` represents an HTML string out of which elements are being created.