# JQuery, remove element(s) from Html string and put back into textarea as HTML

Tags: jquery, string, jquery-selectors, textarea

I have a textarea where user can edit some text and it accepts HTML. In the system, we can add a multimedia file to be added in the textarea. But when someone unlink the multimedia, i need to check if there is any of it in the textarea, remove it and put back on textarea.

So:
I got a textarea like this

```html
<textarea id="edNew-body" class="apply-jHtmlArea" style="width:550px;height:250px;"></textarea>`
```

When i add some multimedia, it comes like this for e.g.:

```html
<audio src="whatever url" controls="controls" class="multimedia_666007" style="display: block; margin: 5px auto 10px; width: 320px; height: 35px; background-color: rgb(227, 227, 227);">-AUDIO-No support for HTML5</audio>`
```

So, when i remove the multimedia, i need to get all html inside the textarea and remove all elements with `class=multimedia_NNNNN` where NNNN will be a number.

I tried the following: [Made a JSFiddle with below code](http://jsfiddle.net/eR5fe/5/)

```js
 dataId = '666007'; //not fixed, will come from somewhere from system
 var $currentHtml = $($("#edNew-body.apply-jHtmlArea").val());
 $currentHtml.find('.multimedia_'+dataId).remove(); //get all but ignore elements with this class
 $("#edNew-body.apply-jHtmlArea").val($currentHtml.html()); //put Html back without elements
```

I have tried the answer from those questions below but they only work on those issues. When i try adapt, i always end with [object Object] or just the first text 'something' without any html.

[JQuery, remove element from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331449/jquery-remove-element-from-string)

[String to jQuery object, how to remove elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350643/string-to-jquery-object-how-to-remove-elements)

[Remove element from html string in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359828/remove-element-from-html-string-in-jquery)

Reading the answers i've learned that i need to use find because since it's user input, it can be or not nested in something (so i can't use `remove('.classhere')`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you place the HTML in a container, then `.find()` will be able to search all the elements (since it never looks at elements at the top level).

Also, since `.html()` only gives you nested HTML content, putting it in a container will allow `.html()` to give you back the entire modified HTML content.

```
$('#rmv').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataId = '666007'; 

      // Put the markup in a new container
    var $currentHtml = $('<div>').append($("#edNew-body.apply-jHtmlArea").val());

      // .find() will now be able to search through all the markup you added
    $currentHtml.find('.multimedia_'+dataId).remove();

      // .html() will now give you back all the markup (though modified)
    $("#edNew-body.apply-jHtmlArea").val($currentHtml.html()); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jR5bc/

Comment: So it was returning always 'something' because since had no container, it was using `.html()` on the first element it found? Since i never used find in a cached $var like that (only in normal DOM, like `$('#someid').find(..)` ), didn't knew about that. So if i tried `$('#someid').find('#someid')` it would never find anything, right? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @RaphaelDDL: Yeah, sort of. `.find()` only looks *inside* the topmost elements. So it was looking for the `'.multimedia_'+dataId` elements *inside* the `<p>` elements. Now you could have used `.filter()` instead of `.find()` to locate it, but that one *only* looks at the top level. So placing the content in a container lets you look at all the elements using `.find()`. And then the same with `.html()`, which only looks inside, so the container solved that too.

Answer (score 2):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZDdWV/

Basically added a wrapper around your HTML text so as to make .find() work (it operates on nodes *under* the caller element)

Comment: Thank you for the answer as well. Since 'am not i am' and you answered on same time, i'll give +1 to both but set accepted to 'am not' since he got less points.